# Kong no plugin named 'upstream-timeout'

Tags: kong

I have a kong `3.0.0` instance with plugins installed like

```
KONG_PLUGINS: bundled,my-custom-plugin
```

I want to add a `upstream-timeout` to one of my route like it's shown in the [docs](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/upstream-timeout/how-to/basic-example/)

```
- name: upstream-timeout
  enabled: true
  route: my-route
  config:
    read_timeout: 2147483646
```

but when I do it I get

```
Error: building state: add defaults to plugin 'upstream-timeout': retrieve schema for upstream-timeout from Kong: HTTP status 404 (message: "No plugin named 'upstream-timeout'")
```

According to [the kong's docs](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/plugin-development/custom-logic/#kong-plugins) this plugin is included in the bundled

I tried to add `upstream-timeout` to `KONG_PLUGINS` env var but it didn't help. How to fix it ?

Comment: Did kong has enterprise license loaded?

Comment: no, I use the open-source version and according to their docs this plugin should be included -> https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/plugin-development/custom-logic/#kong-plugins